# Usage of `block` and `hidden` in Tailwind UI code

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

Looking at the Tailwind UI example source code for the `Navbar` component at https://tailwindui.com/components/application-ui/navigation/navbars, I see there is this part:

```html
<img
    class="block h-8 w-auto lg:hidden"
    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
    alt="Your Company"
/>
<img
    class="hidden h-8 w-auto lg:block"
    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
    alt="Your Company"
/>
```

What's the purpose of this code? It seems it's just showing either of the `img`s depending on whether we are `lg`. But how is that different from just:

```html
<img
    class="block h-8 w-auto"
    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
    alt="Your Company"
/>
```

Comment: It's not rendering a different `img`, so it is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img
class="block h-8 w-auto"
src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
alt="Your Company"/>
```

Output of the above code will be visible across all screens.

```
<img
class="block h-8 w-auto lg:hidden"
src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
alt="Your Company"/>
```

Visible across all screens and hidden on large screens.

```
<img
class="hidden h-8 w-auto lg:block"
src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
alt="Your Company"/>
```

hidden across all devices and visible on large screens only.

it will be beneficial in case you have different images, and you want one image in x screen size and y image on another screen size.

For example, if you have two banners, one for the mobile version and another for the desktop or larger screens, then you would add the classes above to achieve that.

Comment: My question is isn't the two `img` tags just showing the same thing at different screen sizes though? So what's the point?

Comment: updated the answer on OP request

Answer (score 1):

`block lg:hidden` : means it is shown in all screens except large screen sizes and above.

`hidden lg:block` : means it is shown in all large screen sizes and above only, so it is not visible in smaller screens.

this simple hack has been adapted from bootstrap which also has these sm/md/lg conventions to allow you to control responsiveness easier.

update :
different viewport sizes require different image sizes.
for a lot of reasons :
the image is one of those elements that are heavy and expensive in rendering and to be requested from the server.
so preventing a huge image from showing on the mobile version is a good approach, and using a smaller one instead may optimize the performance.
in some cases, there are images that contain real content that you wanna the user to see .. the content on the desktop version of the image should vary in font size and in volume from that in the mobile version of the image.
in a lot of cases, you are going to have to use different images for different viewports.

there are also different approaches which are to use the `picture` tag.
see it on the mdn from here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Comment: My question is isn't the two `img` tags just showing the same thing at different screen sizes though? So what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that, you can have separate styled `img` components for different screen size (that is you can add different utility classes for both)

Here the given example code is useless (or can be written as you mentioned)

The real use case can be understood by the following example

```
<img
    class="block h-8 w-auto border-8 border-indigo-600 lg:hidden"
    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
    alt="Your Company"
/>
<img
    class="hidden h-8 w-auto lg:block"
    src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=500"
    alt="Your Company"
/>
```

Here the border will only be visible on screen size less than `lg`. Similarly you can add utility classes as you like.